# Problem setting wallpaper

Tags: images, wallpaper, xiaomi

*Okay so I want to set an image I saved from Imgur as my wallpaper. But the problem is, I'm not getting the image as I want.. It stretches when I try to set it as a wallpaper.*

[Original image](http://iob.imgur.com/uYGg/gffted8CPy)

**But when I set it as wallpaper it transforms itself as..**

[Wallpaper](http://iob.imgur.com/uYGg/RkFhj8pDPy)

I tried apps from play store and did resizing image, but no progress. Can you guys please help me get it just **fitting my screen** and **original resolution.**

I hope I've made clear what my problem is. Also I'm posting for this topic first time so didn't know which site to put this question on.

Comment: Your current launcher wants the wallpaper to be scrollable, therefore stretching it. If you don't mind and if possible, switch to a launcher that doesn't do this (e.g. Nova).

Comment: No I don't really want to switch my launcher. Isn't there any expert fix that lets me do what I wish without any change of my cute and reliable Mi launcher?